# ConTeXt (mkiv): \seeindex word still appears in english

Tags: context

I need to put a `\seeindex` in my registry. Although I defined my document language to spanish, ConTeXt is still showing that word as "See" in the registry (in spanish it should be something like "Ver" or "Vea"):

```
\mainlanguage[es]
\starttext
test \index{aindex}test
test \seeindex{cindex}{aindex}text
\placeregister[index]
\stoptext
```

I thought `\mainlanguage[es]` would translate those things too... How can I get rid of this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
\setuplabeltext[es][see={ver }]
```

in your document preamble.

The reason you are seeing this behavior is that ConTeXt language codes are not complete. As you can see in [lang-txt.lua](http://gitorious.org/context/context/blobs/origin/tex/context/base/lang-txt.lua) few entries for Spanish are missing. So, if you are native/near native  Spanish speaker, and know the right words for the missing entries, send the list to the ConTeXt [mailing list](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Mailing_Lists) and they will be added in a future release.

Comment: Thank you so much, of course I will be sending my translations as soon as I can.